# jQuery-CSV possibly disables regular jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, jquery-csv

I'm not sure if I'm gettin it right but I just started to use [this jQuery-CSV parser plugin.](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) I wanted to parse CSV file I have stored locally and then, based on results I get from it, use either jQuery's or ajax's notation to get certain data out of urls I provide.

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jQuery')
require ('./jquery.csv.js')

var sample = './analytics.csv';
fs.readFile(sample, 'UTF-8', function(err, csv) {
    $.csv.toObjects(csv, {}, function(err, data) {
        for(var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
            var link = toLink(data[i].Page)
            $.get( link, function(data){
                data[i].Category = $('.category').get(0)
            });

            console.log(data[i])
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting back an error:

```
$.get(link, function (data){
  ^

TypeError: $.get is not a function
at main (E:\Programowanie\lolStats\index.js:16:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Programowanie\lolStats\index.js:37:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

It seems to me like it's looking for **get()** function in the **jquery.csv.js** file instead of regular jquery module I've installed for this project. What would be the easiest way to make both .csv.functions and regular jquery ones work in a same file?

Comment: I think the problem is that `var $ = jQuery = require('jQuery')` doesn't work. Can you verify that after that line `$` has a value and looks like jQuery?

Comment: I think the first line is meant to be `var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')` (note the lowercase require name)

Comment: 'jQuery' has been taken straight from plugin's examples. I've already tried lowercase notation. Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Halcyon yes, I think you may be right. I could've been using wrong jquery module (or a wrong version). Other than that, I may also need to use 'jsdom' to make it work in the end.